# Function is not logging global scope variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate mortgage value based on set of global scope variable but the function is not logging the PV value. What am I doing wrong here? Please don't comment on the code structure, I know it sucks.

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

        /* Logo */
        jQuery("body > nav > div > div > div.navbar-header > h1 > a > img").attr('src', 'https://www.mediapreset.com/clients/spotzer/fenwick/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/FenwickMortgageLogoMMwide.jpg');

        /* Remove theme elements */
        jQuery("section#clients").remove();
        jQuery("section#projects").remove();
        jQuery("section#testimonials").remove();
        jQuery("section#services").remove();
        jQuery("section#calltoaction").remove();
        jQuery("section#about").remove();
        jQuery("section#skills").remove();
        jQuery("section#team").remove();
        jQuery("section#blog").remove();
        jQuery("section#newsletter").remove();

        /* Remove theme elements */
        jQuery('#features').attr('id', 'mortgage');

        /* In put fields for mortgage calculator */
        var borrowAmountLabel  = '<label>How much do you want to borrow?</label>';
        var borrowAmountTotal = '<input type="number"></input>';
        var borrowAmountValue = jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="number"]').val();

        var totalYearsLabel = '<label>Over how many years?</label>';
        var totalYearsInput = '<input type="number"></input>';
        var totalYearsValue = jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(2) > input[type="number"]').val();

        var interestRateLabel = '<label>Interest rate</label>';
        var interestRateInput = '<input type="number"></input>';
        var interestRateValue = jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(3) > input[type="number"]').val();

        /* Reconstruct features section */
        jQuery('#work > div > div > div.col-md-12.heading > h2 > span').text('Mortgage Calculator');
        jQuery('#work > div > div > div.col-md-12.heading > p').remove();

        /* Make multicolumn, empty the div, and add columns */
        jQuery('#work > div > div').attr('class', 'row multi-columns-row');
        jQuery('#work > div > div > div:nth-child(2)').remove();

        jQuery('#work > div > div > div').after('<div class="row">' + '<div class="col-md-4">' + borrowAmountLabel + borrowAmountTotal + '</div>' + '<div class="col-md-4">' + totalYearsLabel + totalYearsInput + '</div>' + '<div class="col-md-4">' + interestRateLabel + interestRateInput + '</div>' + '</div>');

        jQuery('#work > div > div > div:nth-child(4)').after('<button type="submit">Submit<button>');

        jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row').after('<button type="submit">Calculate</button>');

        var calculateButton = document.querySelector("#work > div > div > button");

        calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculateMortgage);

        function calculateMortgage(){
            PV = borrowAmountValue;
            n = totalYearsValue;
            r = interestRateValue;

            console.log(PV);

            leftSide = r * PV;
            rightSide = Math.pow(1 - (1 + r), n);

            var mortgagePayment = Number(leftSide / rightSide);
        }

    });
</script>
```

This is actually the calculation I'm trying to make:

[image]

Any tips would be great!

Comment: Is the value actually populated when the global variable is set? If you log the `borrowAmountValue` after your `jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="number"]').val();` call - what's the value/

Comment: i get undefined

Comment: Post your HTML?

Comment: ^^ there's your answer. `jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="number"]').val()` is undefined,

Comment: No it's not undefined when i log that selector. The var is undefined.

Comment: Declare all the variables at global scope and see if it helps.  Just move the var declarations outside the anonymous function, up top.  and still assign them where you have them.  Or just remove all the "var" keywords.

Comment: no that didn't help, still loggin undefined

Comment: @emporio - Exactly - your selector call returns `undefined` - so why would assigning that variable at a further time yield a different result? `jQuery('#work > div > div > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="number"]').val();` is only ran once, and that's on DOM ready - it is never re-evaluated.

Comment: Just read the values in the calculateMortgage() function...